# Download data from Game Center

Tags: ios, xcode, game-center

I got an iOS app. There is one main function - i need to know all data from iOS Game Center. I talk about game names and scores in this games. I want to collect statistics and scores about all games in user's game center.

How should i do it? Thnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about reading the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/LeaderBoards/LeaderBoards.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH6-SW13) and asking more specific questions if you run into any trouble?

Comment: documentation tell us about how to work with game center if we develop game. but i want to store statistic from it.

Comment: You can't access other games' data. Only your's.

Comment: I need data about all games which user installed and play. Maybe through iCloud or in some other ways?

Comment: It's just not possible, sorry.